# JMeter : java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, jmeter, load-testing

I have created a simple Spring boot Application having a HelloController.

```
Get API: http://localhost:8080/hello
Response: Hello World
```

Now I have created a JMeter Script having 0.1 million concurrent users hitting the above get API.
When I run the JMeter Script, after 30k count, I start getting the error:

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)
```

What is the reason for this? How can I resolve this issue?

- I'm using UBUNTU 18.04 with 8gb RAM.
- While performing the operation, only JMeter and STS was open.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can follow [Lakshmi Narayan answer](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/linux-tuning-support-more-users-jmeter-load-tests-lakshmi-narayan/) to increase available ports:

> Resolution:
>
> 1. Increased the local port range using below command:
>
> echo 1024 65000 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
>
> This allows more local ports to be available.
>
> 2. Enable fast recycling TIME_WAIT sockets as below:
>
> $ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
>
> By default,
>
> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
>
> Output : 0 (disabled by default)
>
> Be cautious if enabled in production environments, since this is our
> internal Environment and machine used only for Jmeter load tests, we
> enabled recycle and resolved the issue.
>
> 3. Enable reuse of sockets as below:
>
> $ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
>
> By default,
>
> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
>
> Output : 0 (disabled by default)
>
> Note: The tcp_tw_reuse setting is particularly useful in environments
> where numerous short connections are open and left in TIME_WAIT state,
> such as web servers. Reusing the sockets can be very effective in
> reducing server load.
>
> After enabling fast recycling and reuse the server could support 5K
> user Load with single Unix box.

Comment: `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle` has been [removed from Linux 4.12.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=4396e46187ca5070219b81773c4e65088dac50cc)