# Java Solr 6.4: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: java, solr

I made a Java console App that queries Solr. The queries are intense because some query By ID (about 500 Ids in the same query) and some by a text property. This App is multi-thread and when I run it in a single thread I have no error, but when I set multi thread, **after having it running for a while**, I start getting the error below:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8983/solr/xx
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:624)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:279)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:268)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:942)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:957)
        at org.example.ProcessFile.getByPropertyFromSolr(ProcessFile.java:570)
        at org.example.ProcessFile.processLinesBulk(ProcessFile.java:226)
        at org.example.ProcessFile.importItemsInFile(ProcessFile.java:117)
        at org.example.ProcessFile.call(ProcessFile.java:97)
        at org.example.ProcessFile.call(ProcessFile.java:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:515)
```

This is my maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
  <version>6.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is the function throwing the error:

```
private SolrDocument getByPropertyFromSolr(String property, String value){

    String urlString = dotenv.get("GAIMP_SOLR_URL");
    HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
    solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());

    try {

        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.set("q", property + ":\"" + ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(value) + "\"");
        query.setStart(0);
        query.setRows(1);
        QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
        SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();

        if (results.size() > 0) {
            return results.get(0);
        }

    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            solr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Knowing that in single-thread I don't have this problem I believe that this happens because the Solr server is taking long to answer to one request while the other thread is firing another query.

Any tips so I don't have this error? Can I use the SolrClient in a way that I set it to wait for the server to respond instead of throwing the error?

Comment: You may have reached the maximum connections per shard. Check out the maxConnectionsPerHost property in https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/format-of-solr-xml.html

Comment: try by having  HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).withConnectionTimeout(10000).withSocketTimeout(60000).build()

Comment: May be related to the underlying settings of your OS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189126/jmeter-java-net-noroutetohostexception-cannot-assign-requested-address-addre